# Generate checkbox on the fly

Tags: c++, qt

I've got a dynamically created list of image extensions that I want to display checkboxes for.
I have a QStringList that contains .png, .jpg, .bmp. This list can be altered by the user so I need to generate a checkbox on the UI for each possibility.

```
QStringList filters;
filters << "*.jpg" << "*.png" << "*.jpeg";
```

I was thinking about a foreach or for loop to achieve this.

```
foreach(QString filt, filters){
    QCheckBox *checkbox = new QCheckBox(filt, this);
}
```

This puts 3 checkboxes on the UI but they are all on top of one another.
How can I space them and also, how can I work with the change in state from check to unchecked on the fly?

Absolutely lost about how to do this when it's generating checkboxes from a stringlist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The checkboxes are stacking on top of one another because you are not adding them to the widget's layout.  Here's an example that will put each checkbox into a vertical layout.

```
QWidget *w = new QWidget;
QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout;

foreach(QString filt, filters){
    QCheckBox *checkbox = new QCheckBox(filt, this);
    checkbox->setChecked(true);
    vbox->addWidget(checkbox);
}

w->setLayout(vbox);
w->show()
```

Read up on QVBoxLayout at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qvboxlayout.html